# WebSocket WriteAsync Error: 'This method may not be called when another write operation is pending

Tags: c#, .net, websocket

I am working on a console application using C# and .NET Core, where I have implemented a WebSocket. However, I am encountering an error when sending data to clients connected to the WebSocket. The error message is as follows:

"This method may not be called when another write operation is pending."

This error seems to occur more frequently as the number of clients and data flow increases. The relevant line of code causing the error is:

```cs
await stream
     .WriteAsync(buffers, 0, buffers.Length, this.CancelToken.Token)
     .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I am looking for guidance on how to resolve this issue and prevent data loss. If you have any suggestions or solutions, please share them. Additionally, it's worth noting that using a queue structure in my system is not suitable because a new data point may override an existing one in the queue during the data flow.

All code:

```cs
private async Task<int> NetStreamSendAsync(byte[] buffers, OpCode opCode = OpCode.Text)
{
    try
    {
        if (!this.Active) return await Task.FromResult(-2).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (!this.Connected)
        {
            this.OnClientError?.Invoke(this, this.EndPoint, new SocketException((int)SocketError.NotConnected));
            return -1;
        }
        if ((opCode == OpCode.Text || opCode == OpCode.Binary) && (buffers == null || buffers.Length == 0)) return 0;
        var stream = this.GetSslStream();
        if (stream == null) return -1;
        if (this.ConnectionType == ConnectionType.WebSocket)
        {
            using (var packet = new WebSocketPacket(this))
                buffers = packet.Packet(buffers, opCode);
        }
        else
        if (buffers == null || buffers.Length == 0)
            return await Task.FromResult(0).ConfigureAwait(false);
        try
        {

            await stream.WriteAsync(buffers, 0, buffers.Length, this.CancelToken.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
            await stream.FlushAsync(this.CancelToken.Token);

            this.LastMessageTime = DateTime.Now;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            LogHelper.Debug($"{SkipData++} - Error: {e.Message} - Veri: {Encoding.GetString(buffers)}");
            this.OnClientError?.Invoke(this, this.EndPoint, new SocketException((int)SocketError.SocketError));
        }
        return await Task.FromResult(buffers.Length).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        LogHelper.Debug($"[NetStreamSendAsync] Error: {e}");
        Console.WriteLine($"[NetStreamSendAsync] Error: {e}");
        throw;
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you  calling this function from different threads/tasks simultaneously?

Comment: Yes, price data is being received and directed to connected clients. When the price comes again, it recalls the code. Due to the rapid arrival of price data, conflicts occur.

Comment: OK you need a concurrent queue, and a single thread that pulls out of that queue and dispatches messages. You cannot use a `NetworkStream` concurrently.

Comment: The queue structure is not suitable for me because when a price is in the queue, the significance of the first price diminishes when the second price of the same product arrives. Therefore, the queue structure is not suitable for my implementation.

Comment: So maybe a `ConcurrentDictionary`? Or a queue which refers back to an object which can itself be updated using locking.